# mPDF converting variable PHP page into PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I am trying to use mPDF to convert a site into PDF.

The thing is that my site is a PHP variable page, which displays information for customers depending on their username and order ID. However, the website name is always the same: personalArea.php.

So, I would like to have a link that says Export to PDF, so the user exports his information.

I am planning on using file_put_contents to put the current page into a HTML file and then use the mPDF to export that HTML into PDF. Is this a good practice? My concern is the volume, I would be creating many HTMLs... I could delete them immediately, but not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used mPDF before and a simple sample code could be:

```
$yourHtml = "ABCD.html";
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('design.css'); //if you wanted some styling
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($yourHtml)); 
unlink($yourHtml); //You could delet your file after showing it if it is just on the fly
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```